# Swagger Generate Subtypes based on enum giving an error

Tags: java, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I have the following API input class

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "importType", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(value = MriImportRequest.class, name = "MRI")})
@Schema(
    description = "Entity",
    discriminatorProperty = "importType",
    discriminatorMapping = {@DiscriminatorMapping(schema = MriImportRequest.class, value = "MRI")})
public abstract class FileImportInput {

  @Schema(
      type = "ImportType",
      example = "MRI",
      required = true,
      description = "The `type` attribute identifies the type of import like MRI")
  @NotNull
  private ImportType importType;

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  @JsonProperty("resourceUri")
  @Schema(
      type = "string",
      example = "riskdata/v1/exposuresets/es1/1223/portfolios/12",
      description = "Resource identification string",
      required = true)
  private String resourceUri;

  public ImportType getImportType() {
    return importType;
  }

  public void setImportType(ImportType importType) {
    this.importType = importType;
  }

  public String getResourceUri() {
    return resourceUri;
  }

  public void setResourceUri(String resourceUri) {
    this.resourceUri = resourceUri;
  }
}
```

Based on import type value I have defined this MriImportRequest class

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeName("MRI")
public class MriImportRequest extends FileImportInput {

  @Schema(
      type = "MriImportSettings",
      example = "{ \"geohaz\":true}",
      description = "Contains all settings")
  @JsonProperty("settings")
  private MriImportSettings settings;

  public MriImportSettings getSettings() {
    return settings;
  }

  public void setSettings(MriImportSettings settings) {
    this.settings = settings;
  }
}
```

I have the following entry in POM for swagger code gen.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <apiPackage>com.rms.sdk.api</apiPackage>
                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                <inputSpec>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                <invokerPackage>com.rms.sdk.invoker</invokerPackage>
                <language>java</language>
                <modelPackage>com.rms.sdk.model</modelPackage>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <version>${swagger.codegen.version}</version>
</plugin>
```

In the swagger generated class I get the following error. I am not able to understand why

When I try to build the project I am getting ,  incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to com.rms.sdk.model.FileImportInput.ImportTypeEnum, Below is the code that is erroring out, its the this.importType line.

```java
public FileImportInput() {
  this.importType = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

```
Import type Class is below -- 

public enum ImportType {
  MRI(1, "MRI");
  private final Integer code;
  private final String value;

  ImportType(int code, String value) {
    this.code = code;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static ImportType getById(int id) {
    for (ImportType typeOfImport : ImportType.values()) {
      if (typeOfImport.code.equals(id)) {
        return typeOfImport;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public int getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your `ImportType` Class?

Comment: I added it to the body Can you please help out and take a look

Comment: Import type Class is below -- 

public enum ImportType {
  MRI(1, "MRI");
  private final Integer code;
  private final String value;

  ImportType(int code, String value) {
    this.code = code;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static ImportType getById(int id) {
    for (ImportType typeOfImport : ImportType.values()) {
      if (typeOfImport.code.equals(id)) {
        return typeOfImport;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public int getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

The generator has no idea what the enum is.  If you open your schema in swagger, that `importType` field doesn't exist.  So, Jackson is interpreting the type as a string.  When you try to map the string to the enum, Jackson doesn't know what to do.  Remember, the enum itself is not a String, so Jackson needs instruction.  Update your enum to use the `@JsonValue` as follows and it should work fine.

```java
public enum ImportType
{
  MRI(1, "MRI");
  private final Integer code;
  private final String value;

  ImportType(int code, String value)
  {
    this.code = code;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static ImportType getById(int id)
  {
    for (ImportType typeOfImport : ImportType.values()) {
      if (typeOfImport.code.equals(id)) {
        return typeOfImport;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public int getCode()
  {
    return code;
  }

  @JsonValue
  public String getValue()
  {
    return value;
  }
}
```

You could also add a helper method with the `@JsonCreator` annotation, such as below.

```java
  @JsonCreator
  public static ImportType ofValue(String value)
  {
    for (var typeOfImport : ImportType.values()) {
      if (typeOfImport.value.equals(value)) {
        return typeOfImport;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Finally, another option is to make a custom deserializer.  This is easy enough to accomplish by creating the below deserializer and adding the `@JsonDeserialize(using = ImportTypeDeserializer.class)` annotation to your enum:

```java
public class CustomEnumDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Distance> {

    @Override
    public Distance deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);

        String value = node.get("ImportType").asString();

        for (var distance : Distance.values()) {
           
            if (distance.getValue().equals(value) {
                return distance;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

If you have no control over the enum, you can still use a custom deserializer and register it with your object mapper by placing the annotation above the field in your abstract class:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "importType", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(value = MriImportRequest.class, name = "MRI")})
@Schema(
    description = "Entity",
    discriminatorProperty = "importType",
    discriminatorMapping = {@DiscriminatorMapping(schema = MriImportRequest.class, value = "MRI")})
public abstract class FileImportInput {

  @Schema(
      type = "ImportType",
      example = "MRI",
      required = true,
      description = "The `type` attribute identifies the type of import like MRI")
  @NotNull
  @JsonDeserialize(using = ImportTypeDeserializer.class)
  private ImportType importType;

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  @JsonProperty("resourceUri")
  @Schema(
      type = "string",
      example = "riskdata/v1/exposuresets/es1/1223/portfolios/12",
      description = "Resource identification string",
      required = true)
  private String resourceUri;

  public ImportType getImportType() {
    return importType;
  }

  public void setImportType(ImportType importType) {
    this.importType = importType;
  }

  public String getResourceUri() {
    return resourceUri;
  }

  public void setResourceUri(String resourceUri) {
    this.resourceUri = resourceUri;
  }
}
```

Regardless of the route you take though, I highly recommend creating a schema for the `FileImportInput` class and overriding it's TypeMapping in your configuration.  The primary purpose of the swagger interface that comes with openapi is to document your rest service.  As it is, your clients have no way of knowing what values are acceptable for the `ImportType` without you stating it in your description.

You can do this by creating the schema (possibly calling it `GeneratedFileImportInput`) and setting it to mimic your `abstract FileImportInput`, and then in your maven plugin, change the configuration for the `typeMappings` to have `GeneratedFileImportInput=FileImportInput` and `importMappings` to have `FileImportInput=my.package.of.FileImportInput`.  This will replace all generated occurances of the `GeneratedFileImportInput` with your version.

You can also take it a step further by adding the `GeneratedFileImportInput` to your `.openapi-generator-ignore` to ensure the file isn't generated at all.

By doing this, you can ensure any clients of your REST API that are using the swagger ui (or any other ui) can see the schema as a part of your documentation without impacting your code base.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and i now have a good understanding. But i am still getting [ERROR] /Users/samarnath/RmsOne/import-export/platform-analytics/util/platform-analytics-java-client/target/generated-sources/swagger/src/main/java/com/rms/sdk/model/FileImportInput.java:[78,52] incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to com.rms.sdk.model.FileImportInput.ImportTypeEnum
I tried all the approaches, @JsonValue, Using Custom deserializer and nothing is working. and i change ImportTypeEnum to just have MRI and initializing in default constructor nothing works